# Browser addon to automatically opt-in for cookies - EU cookie law

Tags: javascript, cookies, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In EU we have this law that requires web pages to request permission to store cookies. Most of us know about cookies and agree to them but still are forced to accept them explicitly everywhere. So I plan to write this add on (ff & chrome) that will automatically add session cookie with standard name that would mean agreement. Just wondering about few things:

1) What should be the name of the cookie? What should be the value? Should I cover only user agreement option? My proposition is 
_cookieok=1
the benefit is that it is short, yet descriptive.

2) Should I add only single cookie - the one I suggested above? Many pages do it in different ways already. They use different cookie names and check for different values. I thought maybe use names and values from popular scripts like http://cookiecuttr.com/ but I don't want to increase upload traffic with a number of mostly not needed cookies.

3) Should I differentiate between types of cookies? I have seen here http://demo.cookieconsent.silktide.com/ there are multiple cookie types you can opt-in/opt-out?

4) Does this have chances to become popular or is it better to use something like point 2 - adding multiple values manually?

5) I could probably also remove those cookies after some event (like after all js onload functions have finished) but I could not find proper hook in firefox addons. Plus maybe some people would like to do filtering out of the script on server side so maybe it is better to keep sending the cookie.

Is there something I have not thought about? My suggested code is in case of FF:

```js
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptWhen: 'start',
    contentScript: 'document.cookie="_cookieok=1;path=/";'
});
```

**Update**

To explain how does it work
1) Most sites already compliant to cookie law do something like this:

```
if ($.cookie('_cookieok') == null) {
    $('#cookie-close').on('click', function (evt) {
        $.cookie('cookieok', 1, 300); 
    });
    $('.cookie-prompt').show();
}
```

so if we agree on same name existance of such ff plugin would be possible. If someone does not plugin - site will prompt him. If has site would recognize addon added cookie as their own.

Comment: If you downvoted provide a comment

Comment: Would be useful to know the reason.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. It's just that you'll have to use dom manipulation to read and find the accept button.Because all sites use different ways to accept and use cookies. There's no standard way to enable cookies on a website.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what the point of this really is to be honest?

If you're looking to build something that would be used across a portfolio of sites you manage, then you're probably pushing your luck to force a user to install an extension simply to show they accept your cookies. If it's aimed at a wider audience, i.e. potentially anyone using any website, then the other issue you'll have is getting both users to see the benefit of installing another extension and secondly website operators to write the code necessary to detect your cookie and act accordingly.

Most sites seem to be striving to make cookies and the associated obligations under the legislation as unintrusive as possible - requiring installation of an extension & changes to website code seems to be heading in the opposite direction..

Comment: Site owners already write code that detects their own cookie set when user agrees on cookie polity. Users have to keep accepting cookies on every page they visit - the problem. This extension will stop users from clicking on the accept cookie polity popup I am sure you have clicked many times.

Comment: But only on those sites that decide to implement support for it...? Personally speaking, clicking an "accept" button on the first time I visit a website (assuming it prompts) is less hassle and effort than installing another browser extension, and trying to then determine whether or not I could use it with a particular site..

Comment: @llapinski I think you're missing a fundamental technical point here - how are you going to guarantee you're using the right cookie string on every single website, without buy-in from the developers of each of these sites? For example, let's say I want to call my value _cookiesAccepted. How does your plugin cope with that to provide anything close to useful functionality?

Comment: That is right. That is the problem I don't know how to solve. However there are already few popular free scripts that are deployed on thousands of web sites. I mentioned one of them in my question.

Comment: So your question here is "how do I make people agree to use a standard name for cookies"? I don't know how you'd expect to get an answer for that here, this is a site for technical problems, not social ones

Comment: @llapinski I suspect you're trying to create a solution to a problem that doesn't exist. Cookies and implementations of cookies on websites have been around for years and take millions of different forms. Trying to get everyone to standardise their implementation to work with your code just isn't going to happen.

Comment: To clarify: noble intention, reasonable idea to solve what you perceive to be an annoyance...but from an implementation standpoint, this is akin to getting everybody in the world to wear a red jumper. Only those who like red, or those who agree with your reason for wearing red, will comply. Plus, you haven't even got your message out to the masses yet so you're at square 1. You need the buy-in before you build this, or it's a waste of time and energy

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys. However I am not such defeatist. There are so many ways this can be done. I would like to do this as simply as possible: write free jquery plugin plus having creators of other free scripts agree on this would be nice. There are however other ways for instance AdBlock way - where people mark things and data is synced.

Comment: @llapinski Don't think we're being defeatist, just practical.

Comment: There _are_ so many ways this could be done. And all of them require that you convince hundreds of thousands of people you've never met to do things your way. Talk to people who create standards for a living, they'll tell you what you're actually up against here, the word 'defeatist' takes on a whole new meaning to them. Don't get me wrong, best of luck to you from me, but I won't be holding my breath that this will become an international standard any time soon. And, regrettably, Stack Overflow isn't the right place to solicit ideas on how to get those developers on board with your standard.